# JQuery: Hover to show/hide individual object

Tags: jquery

Basically I need to hover over an anchor to display the "data-meta" div. Works just fine but when there's multiple td and divs, one hover displays all of them. My question is how can I show/hide them individually? Code snippets below.

```
<td>
<a href="#">Item</a>
<div class="data-meta">
    <a href="#">Edit</a> | <a href="#">Disable</a> | <a href="#">Delete</a>
</div>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function(){        
    $("td").hover(
        function () {
        $('.data-meta').show();
        },
        function () {
        $('.data-meta').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass a [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) to your selector:

```
$(function() {
 $('td').hover(
  function() {
   $('.data-meta', this).show();
   // Other cool stuff goes here
  },
  function () {
   $('.data-meta', this).hide();
   // Other cool stuff goes here
  }
 );
});
```

Comment: @James: Exactly. `$('.class', this);` is effectively the same as `$(this).find('.class');`.

Answer (score 0):

To attach the even only to a single `<td>` it would be easiest to add an ID:   `<td id="menutd">`  then use `$('td#menutd')` when attaching your event.

In this particular example, the `$('.data-meta')` will find all `class='data-meta'` in the document, you can make it search only within the matched `td` by making it `$('.data-meta', this)` instead.  The second parameter (`this`) defines an element to search within... jQuery event handlers always have `this` set as the element that the event is triggering on.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is actually grabbing all TD's as opposed to the specific item. I would give the href an ID and target that, you also can use the toggle call instead.

```
<td>
<a href="#" id="hide-show">Item</a>
<div class="data-meta">
    <a href="#">Edit</a> | <a href="#">Disable</a> | <a href="#">Delete</a>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){        
    $("#hide-show").hover(
        function () {
        $('.data-meta').toggle();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `$("td")` affects every single td in the document. If you want to control this individually, try something like this:

```
<td onmouseover="$('.data-meta', this).show();" onmouseout="$('.data-meta', this).hide();">
<a href="#">Item</a>
<div class="data-meta">
    <a href="#">Edit</a> | <a href="#">Disable</a> | <a href="#">Delete</a>
</div>
```